# Echo in HTML Form after POST

Tags: php, html

I make submit with POST-Function

```html
 <div><button type="submit" id="myBtn" >buy</button></div>
```

this button belongs to my form

```html
<form id="myForm" method="post" >
```

here are my other inputs in the form:

```html
      <input type="text" name="number" id="number" value="<?php if (isset($_POST["price"])) { echo $number;}?>"></div>
    <div><label>Gewinnklasse:</label>
        <input type="text" name="class" id="class" value="<?php if (isset($_POST["price"])) { echo $class; }?>"></div>
    <div><label>Zustand:</label>
        <input type="text" name="zustand" id="state" value="<?php if (isset($_POST["price"])) {echo $state;} ?>"></div>
    <div><label>Preis:</label>
        <input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="<?php if (isset($_POST["price"])) {echo $preis;} ?>" ></div>
```

In the PHP-Code there is a JSON-File with data in it, the php part looks like:

```html
<?php
$str = file_get_contents("win_lose.json");
$json = json_decode($str, true);

$preisArray = array();
foreach ($json as $value) {
    $price[] = $value["price"];
}

if (isset($_POST["price"])) {
    $key = array_search($_POST["price"], array_column($json, 'price'));
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $class = $json[$key]['class'];
    $number = $json[$key]['number'];
    $state = $json[$key]['state'];
}
?>
```

Customer enters price, hits the button and the other information from the whole Object are filled in the form (class,state,number)

At this moment i got PHP-Code which echo in my directly in my Forms between the HTML-Code, but i dont want any PHP-Code in my HTML. So every echo should be in the PHP script. Is there a method to get access to my html-elements from my php script? Like document.getElementById in JS.

Here is an example of my JSON-File:

```html
{
  "win_lose": [
    {
      "state": "closed",
      "number": 1,
      "class": "A",
      "price": 10
    },
    {
      "state": "closed",
      "number": 2,
      "class": "B",
      "price": 20
    },
```

i put it in my php-script with

```html
$str = file_get_contents("win_lose.json");
$json = json_decode($str, true);
```

EDIT

Comment: I've only got to your last code block so far, and I'm seeing `$preisArray` created by never used, followed by a loop that sets `$price` as an array. Are these supposed to be the same variables? Also, inside your POST block, you are overwriting `$price` , is that intended?

Comment: "every echo should be in the PHP script", I used to do that in my early days, and it really lead to ugly code from a maintenance standpoint that I eventually undid it all. If you can, try using a templating language like Twig which help with escaping and limiting what variables/functions can be used on the "HTML side". If you can't, out of the box, PHP does not have access to a page, however you could try to build your own parser with DOMDocument or similar, but I think it would get ugly really fast.

Comment: What is the issue with the php existing between the html? you know it cannot be seen from a browser in any way right? PHP doesn't behave like JS all of it's data is loaded with the first page load... you can use JS for this if you want instead of PHP easily!

Comment: My suggestion/preference is to keep PHP and HTML as separate as possible, and the only PHP parts that should be in the HTML are conditionals, loops and echos, with the occasional variable setting or `include` if really needed. When you need to switch to PHP, do it briefly and get back to HTML, and don't be afraid to do it many times in the same file. (This is mostly what template languages do, too.) If you need complexity, wrap that in a function/method and keep it elsewhere. Also, get a good IDE that will format and indent for you.